# This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'any[]' and 'string' have no overlap

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ecmascript-6

```js
let dataTable: any[];

if (dataTable != "")
{
    for (let i = 0; i < dataTable.length; i++) 
    {
        idNum = i;

        table.innerHTML += `<td>${1}</td>
                           <td>${dataTable[i].title}</td>
                           <td>${dataTable[i].price}</td>
                           <td>${dataTable[i].tax || "0"}</td>
                           <td>${dataTable[i].ads || "0"}</td>
                           <td>${dataTable[i].discount || "0"}</td>
                           <td>${dataTable[i].category}</td>
                           <td class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></td>
                           <td class="edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></td>`;
    }
} 
else 
{
    console.log("yas");
}
```

```
error TS2367: This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'any[]' and 'string' have no overlap.
```

Comment: Don't use type `any`?

Comment: The formatting is not great here, but you told the compiler that `dataTable` is an  array, and then immediately check it to see if it's the empty string.  But arrays are not strings, and so the check is suspicious, and probably indicative of a mistake.  So, what's your question exactly?